# Find the tangent cone of a point on a sphere

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

Can anyone help me with the following problem? I have looked around the forum but have found no solution to this problem.

In the problem the tangent cone of a point a is defined as the cone with vertex 0 induced by the tangent directions at a.

The tangent direction is a unit vector h such that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=a$ in the space V in the direction of h. Here in the direction of h means that $\left\|\frac{x_n-a}{\|x_n-a\|}\right\|\rightarrow h$.

Let $V=\{x:\|x\|=r\}$ and $p\in V$. I need to find the tangent cone of V at p.

Hence, I need to find all h such that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\in V$ such that $x_n\rightarrow p$ and $\left\|\frac{x_n-a}{\|x_n-a\|}\right\|\rightarrow h$.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Edit: I can draw the solution in a $R^2$ space and see that the solution is the tangent hyperplane to the point p but I do not see how I can show it formally.

Comment: From where is the problem taken?

Comment: It is a problem from my mathematics course. The subject of the problem set to which this problem belongs is constrained optimisation.